Non-blocking Tkinter window
I have read multiple similar questions & answers, but somehow still have not understood how to apply them to my particular use case. The best I found was using Tkinter with Thread:
from Tkinter import *
import threading

class App(threading.Thread):

    def __init__(self, tk_root):
        self.root = tk_root
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.start()

    def run(self):
        loop_active = True
        while loop_active:
            user_input = raw_input("Give me your command! Just type \"exit\" to close: ")
            if user_input == "exit":
                loop_active = False
                self.root.quit()
                self.root.update()
            else:
                label = Label(self.root, text=user_input)
                label.pack()

ROOT = Tk()
APP = App(ROOT)
LABEL = Label(ROOT, text="Hello, world!")
LABEL.pack()
ROOT.mainloop()

But here the parallel task is the raw_input, which is already part of the App itself. But what if I want to have instead two instances of App each in its thread running in parallel? Or App + open3d visualization? How would I modify this code to have responsive Tkinter GUI in one thread, without explicitly relying on some function input?
Another solution I found utilized Toplevel. Is that indeed the correct approach for this problem? Would it not complain that Tkinter does not like working with threads, as multiple other answers to similar questions pointed out? Example:
from tkinter import *
import threading
import time

class Show_Azure_Message(Toplevel):
    def __init__(self,master,message):
        Toplevel.__init__(self,master) #master have to be Toplevel, Tk or subclass of Tk/Toplevel
        self.title('')
        self.attributes('WM_DELETE_WINDOW',self.callback)
        self.resizable(False,False)
        Label(self,text=message,font='-size 25').pack(fill=BOTH,expand=True)
        self.geometry('250x50+%i+%i'%((self.winfo_screenwidth()-250)//2,(self.winfo_screenheight()-50)//2))

    def callback(self): pass

BasicApp=Tk()
App = Show_Azure_Message(BasicApp,'Hello')
for i in range(0,2):
    print(i)
    time.sleep(1)

App.destroy()


Taking a step back for a moment, could you clarify what exactly it is you're trying to do?

@JRiggles as mentioned in text: "But what if I want to have instead two instances of App each in its thread running in parallel? Or App + open3d visualization?". For now I only managed to first visualize Tkinter app, close it, and then visualize open3d app. I need to have both of them interactive and running simultaneously.

You are using older python version.  It will work for me using python 3.12.4

@toyotaSupra what works for you?.. You should no code and says "it works for you". I am also using Python 3.12.

The raw_input("Give me your command! Just type \"exit\" to close: ")  should be input("Give me your command! Just type \"exit\" to close: ")

@Valeria Generally there's nothing preventing you from running multiple instances of the same tkinter app in parallel. If your app is hanging on a long-running function (e.g. whatever the visualization is doing), that's the part that you should be running in a separate thread. Does that make sense?

The second script, comment out this #self.attributes('WM_DELETE_WINDOW',self.callback)

@toyotaSupra you're technically correct, but I'd advise against using input in a tkinter app anyway, since it's not a console app

@JRiggles. It was written older than python 2.7

@toyotaSupra What was? OP said they're using 3.12, so your right in saying that it should be input and not raw_input, but my point is they shouldn't be using either one in a GUI app.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

@JRiggles the code is combining GUI app with bash console just as an example... I need to have Tkinter GUI and Open3D GUI running in parallel. Anyway, ChatGPT helped me more than this thread, and after several hours I finally have it done via simple multiprocessing, having Tkinter in main thread, and second GUI in separate process. Not sure if it would also work with Tkinter + Tkinter, but Tkiner + Open3d is enough for me.

Multiprocessing is far easier to get working, but more expensive and harder to work with in the end, depending on your needs. I wanted to suggest you this solution, but your question isn't really clear to me.

line 20, in run
label = Label(self.root, text=user_input)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
RuntimeError: main thread is not in main loop

Also I do apologize if you had a bad experience here, but be aware that there are people reading your question and simply unsure how to address it since your question is way too broad for [so] and simply skip it because of it.

@Thingamabobs thankfully, that is just a temporary workaround. My final goal is to use rerun.io for these purposes, at least when they implement the onclick for their visualizer.

If I took a wild guess, I think you do plan on showing your data model in a tkinter application and visualize it with a different toolkit (e.g open3D). The approach I would suggest you is to have your GUI in the main thread and follow the canonical of working with threads in tkinter. Running your app multiple times can be achieved through subprocess. You also could look into github and pyopengltk, moderngl (has an tkinter example) or even Tcl3D if you are willing to go that far.
